# Find if IP exists in range of CIDR IPs by hand Python

Tags: python, ip, cidr

I have a list of IPs with a CIDR notation such as:

10.10.1.32/27

What i want to do is check if an IP falls into that range. So i want to be able to see if 10.10.1.44 falls in there, which it would, or that 10.10.1.90 does not.

I know there are many python libraries that currently do this such as ipcalc and netaddr.

But i wan't to do this by hand. I know i need to convert the IPs to binary, and do some calculations based on that. I feel like i am pretty close but i'm not 100% on bitwise operations in Python

I found one here that does this for C, but i can't find how to do it in Python without using a library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily adapt the script [here](https://gist.github.com/boubakr92/4344773). It will give you the network and broadcast addresses, say N1.N2.N3.N4 and B1.B2.B3.B4. Then you just check if the address you're testing A1.A2.A3.A4 is within the two by doing

```
if N1 <= A1 <= B1 and .... and N4 <= A4 <= B4:
    return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the netaddr package has what you need. I am actually doing all IP computations with this library.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr